# Equation of the normal to the curve

Tags: calculus

Work out the equation of the normal to the curve $y=2x^3 - x^2 + 1$ at the point $(1,2)$ give your answer in the form $y=mx+c$
I have done $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and got $6x^2 -2x$, but I am unsure what to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps you need to follow.

Now you have $6x^2-2x$ as the derivative, you can substitute $x=1$ to get the gradient at the point $(1,2)$, which is $4$. If $t$ is the gradient of the tangent, then $-\frac {1}t$ is the gradient of the normal (if you multiply the gradients of two perpendicular lines you get $-1$).

You therefore need to find the equation of the line which now has known gradient, and which passes through the given point.

Comment: I was going to post an answer but I stopped. You explain much better. +1